# How to catch Apache's 403 error in PHP / Kohana?

Tags: php, apache, kohana

My website is running on Kohana v3, and I have set up customized error page like below in bootstrap.php

```
try
{
    // Attempt to execute the response
    $request->execute();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{ 
      .... error page re-direct.
}
```

It works fine with 404 error.

I also have some folders that cannot be directly accessed but they have to be located under the www root. I put the .htaccess to protect these folders

```
# nobody can access this folder from Browser
Deny from all
```

When user type in the URL in the browser to access files under this folder, an Apache 403 error will be shown in plain text like this:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /private_folder on this server.

I want to customize this error and handle it in Kohana. However, I find that Apache fully controls the 403 error, and does not even call the index.php under this situation.

Any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using .htaccess to lock that area down, you could do it in code. [PHP's header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) could be used to send the 403 status.

Another approach would be to set up a custom error document for 403 errors in Apache, and point this at a script to handle the error. Refer to the [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument) documentation on how to do this, but it would be something along these lines:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /custom_403_handler.php
```

Comment: ErrorDocument works great. I redirect the 403 error to my Error controller by this: `ErrorDocument 403 /error/404`